# Preserve reputation from shut-down betas on flair and network profile

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, flair

As most of us know, a number of betas were unfortunately [shut down](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/) recently due to lack of activity.

On one of of these betas (Literature), I had just enough reputation for it to appear on my flair (probably about 250). However, after those sites went down, the "Li" icon was nowhere to be seen, and I was 250 rep down. Admittedly, that's not a lot of rep, but that means that many users with thousands of rep on these sites lost all of it, never to be seen again. I imagine the amount lost could be quite upsetting when these users see their network rep plummet, so I have a suggestion:

Although the betas themselves will no longer be online, I propose that the reputation users earned from these betas be preserved in their network account, and the icon still appear on their flair (obviously, only given that they had >200). This way, they can be recognized as having made those (sometimes very significant) contributions and will have some memento of the time spent on the betas. It seems to me that this is the least SE can offer as a token of appreciation to the "veterans" of late betas, although I recognize that there may be some technical inconveniences involved.

What do you think?

Answer (score 5):

I agree with the spirit of the suggestion, but I don't think preserving the icons of failed sites is a healthy idea.

This would have to work some other way - how about some sort of network-wide "veteran" badge for example?

Comment: I agree with the badge idea, but I actually think preserving the icons of "failed" sites could be beneficial. From the linked [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/): "[The closed sites] will likely make great Stack Exchange sites… someday." Preserving the icons could be a reminder that *some day* those topics may return, and would indicate, to an outsider, those who may be interested in a renewed attempt at a site.